# Unable to delete hidden files in Linux with Java

Tags: java, linux, hidden-files

Environment:

- Linux Ubuntu 14.04LTS
- Java 1.7

Current code:

```
String fileName = ".fileName";
            try {
                java.io.File F = new java.io.File(fileName);
                java.io.RandomAccessFile RF = new java.io.RandomAccessFile(F,"rwd");
                RF.close();
                boolean deleted = F.delete();                   
                System.out.println("File was deleted: " + deleted);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                System.out.println("Unable to access file: " + e1.getMessage());
            }
```

File still exists, yet deleted is true and no `FileNotFoundException` is caught.

Comment: Won't the file still be open when you call `F.delete`?  Try closing the `RF` first.  `File#delete` returns a `boolean` indicating the success of the operation, you might want to check it

Comment: Make sure your file is in the path you think it is. And, why are you opening the file before you call `delete()`?

Comment: Edited code to reflect @MadProgrammer 's suggestion. Weird that it says it's deleted but the file's still there.

Comment: Turns out it was a whitespace issue. String.trim() resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

One of the following is probably your problem:

- are you deleting in the right directory? I notice you specify not an absolute path, but a relative path that doesn't imply you're specifying a relative path on purpose. You may be deleting something in another directory.
- Close the file `F`, you are leaving the handle open and I'm not sure the consequences.
- How are you verifying "it's still there"? `ls` and not `cat` or `nano` or anything right?

And other debugging:

- does opening the RF matter? (It shouldn't).
- Does it actually matter that it's a hidden file? What file are you *actually* deleting?
- does this happen in different directories?
- does this happen if you lock read/write access to the file in question with `chmod`? If you block reads what fails, if you block writes what fails? I strongly suspect this will elucidate your problem.

Comment: Turns out it was a whitespace issue. String.trim() resolved the issue. It seems misleading that delete returns true if the file didn't exist in the first place. But very helpful suggestions nonetheless. Thank you.

Comment: @cbrad consider posting that as an answer and accept. Ideally describe your debugging steps in figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but this might be useful to someone else since nobody pointed this out. The catch block is catching an exception that will never be thrown. If you want to know whether or not a file was present and then deleted use java.nio.Files.delete(Path). If the file is not there it will throw a FileNotFoundException. Check the javadocs, this is all spelled out in detail.